# Gridview -Flutter Is it possible to show specifc number of grid in flutter (i.e for mobile wanna display 2 grid and for tab wanna show 5 grid)

Tags: flutter, gridview

Hi I am creating a grid view where I wanna show different number of grids in different platforms eg in mobile just wanna display 2 grid and in tab wanna display approx 5 grids.

```
GridView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  child: ProductCard(product: products[index]),
                );
              },
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: isTablet(context) ? 3 : 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: isTablet(context) ? 60.0 : 20.0,
                mainAxisExtent: isTablet(context) ? 180 : 170,
              ),
              itemCount: products.length,
            ),
```

Now I am implementing like this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a couple of ways.

A. Use a package ([package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus)) to identify the device and change the crossAxisCount accordingly.

B. Use MediaQuery to detect if the device is in landscape or portrait mode. Tablets are in landscape mode and phones in portrait.

```
if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait){
// is portrait
   isTablet = false;
}else{
 // is landscape
   isTablet = true;
}
```

C. Or use OrientationBuilder to do the same as MediaQuery

```
 return OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          if (orientation == Orientation.landscape){
             isTablet = true;
          } else {
             isTablet = false;
          }
          return GridView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SizedBox(
                child: ProductCard(product: products[index]),
            );
          },
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: orientation == isTablet ? 3 : 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: isTablet ? 60.0 : 20.0,
            mainAxisExtent: isTablet ? 180 : 170,
          ),
          itemCount: products.length,
        );
   },
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have issue with itemcount not with cross axis count. Let me elaborate more for example I have 40 items in list calling products.length that will gonna show all 40 items  not for specifc device like for mobile I just wanna display 10 items that will take 5 grids (2 in each row)  means that wanna just apply condition on itemcount

Comment: Then you should Edit your question to match what you're asking for.